# Como verificar se o primeiro e segundo caracter de uma string é número?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, condição

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema e preciso fazer uma validação de uma string. Caso o primeiro e segundo caracter seja número, o sistema deve retornar erro.

Essa lógica que coloquei aqui consegue verificar se tem algum número na string (em qualquer posição). Preciso retornar erro (True, nesse caso), apenas se tiver número na primeira e segunda casa.

```
str1 = "python1"

if any(map(str.isdigit, str1)) == True:
    raise ValueError("possui numero na string em alguma posicao")
```

Alguma sugestão para desenvolver essa condição?

Answer (score 5):

O seu código basicamente verifica se a string inteira contém qualquer número.

Como você quer verificar somente os dois primeiros caracteres, é necessário limitar o escopo dessa busca.

Existem, obviamente, várias maneiras de se fazer isso. Uma delas é utilizar um *slice*:

```
>>> 'python1'[:2]
'py'
```

Então:

```
>>> all(map(str.isdigit, 'python1'[:2]))
False

>>> all(map(str.isdigit, '1python'[:2]))
False

>>> all(map(str.isdigit, '12python'[:2]))
True
```

Repare que, nesse caso, ao utilizar `all`, adota-se a semântica do operador lógico E. Se a semântica de OU fosse necessária, deveria se utilizar a função `any`.

Conforme observado pelo [Woss, nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/528453/como-verificar-se-o-primeiro-e-segundo-caracter-de-uma-string-%C3%A9-n%C3%BAmero#comment957588_528455), para a semântica de E, pode-se utilizar o método `isdigit` diretamente, o que simplifica bastante:

```
>>> '12python'[:2].isdigit()
True
```

Comment: A função `isdigit` já avalia toda a string, então pode simplificar para `var[:2].isdigit()` apenas

Comment: @Woss, sim, mas nesse caso adota-se semântica de E.

Comment: "*caso o primeiro **e** segundo caracter seja número, deve retornar erro*" xD

Comment: @Woss Antes da pergunta ser editada, uma das frases tinha "ou". Depois do edit foi esclarecido que deve ser "e".

Comment: Obrigado, @Woss, eu editei a resposta.

Comment: @hkotsubo isso mesmo, editei para "e". Foi erro meu. Valeu pela contribuição, galera!

Answer (score 4):

No caso de serem apenas dois caracteres, pode verificar um a um:

```py
if len(str1) >= 2 and str1[0].isdigit() and str1[1].isdigit():
    raise ValueError('erro')
```

Repare também que não precisa fazer `if algo == True`, pode fazer simplesmente `if algo`. E deve-se verificar o tamanho da string antes, para garantir que há pelo menos dois caracteres (senão dará erro ao tentar acessar um índice que não existe).

---

Mas falta definir o que fazer se a string tiver apenas um caractere (ou se for vazia). Nesse caso, uma alternativa seria usar *slices*:

```py
if str1[:2].isdigit():
    raise ValueError('erro')
```

`str1[:2]` retorna uma outra string contendo apenas os 2 primeiros caracteres de `str1`. [Leia aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211) para saber mais sobre *slices*.

Repare que para verificar se todos os caracteres são dígitos, posso usar `isdigit` diretamente na string gerada pelo *slice*.

No caso, a diferença para o código anterior é que, se a string tiver somente 1 caractere, então `str1[:2]` retornará a string inteira, e `isdigit` retornará `True` se este caractere for número. E se a string for vazia, `str1[:2]` também retorna a string inteira, e nesse caso nunca entrará no `if`, pois a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) diz que `isdigit` retorna `False` se a string for vazia.

Answer (score 2):

a String nada mais é do que um array de chars ou seja você pode acessar as 2 primeiras posições do seu texto como se fosse uma lista e fazer a verificação.

```
x = "1texto"

if x[0].isdigit() or x[1].isdigit():
  print("ERRO")
```

Comment: Acho que valeria adicionar na resposta um alerta sobre a validação do tamanho da string nesse caso, pois se possuísse menos que dois caracteres daria erro no `x[1]` (talvez só comentar que isso foi deixado de fora para simplificar a resposta, mas que seria crucial para a solução final)